# Does summernote allow Microsoft word document upload

Tags: summernote

Does summernote allow Microsoft word document upload through it's UI just like image upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by implementing a custom button/function. If you want to show a thumbnail of a file and a link to download the document you can do this by managing your html. If you want to show the entire document on summernote I think it's not so trivial, you will need to find third-party libs for converting word format to html.
Take a look at https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-button.